# FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apple-silicon

i'm trying to compile my Java project on IntelliJ, but i have this issue:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error decoding percent encoded characters
    at java.base/sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:218)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:1218)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:491)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:485)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:484)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:452)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:321)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:757)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:435)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at open/src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed

Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

(jdk-19, apple silicon)

Thanks

Maybe is due to my JDK and some configurations about Java

Comment: Do you have to use jdk-19? In IntelliJ you can choose a lower jdk version as your project jdk. Curious if you would get passed issues if you used a lower jdk version.

Comment: @ZackMacomber i tried with jdk-17 and i have the same issue. I tested it also with other computers, and it works with jdk-19, but not on mine.

Comment: Does https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281300/Scratch-Java-file-wont-run-if-theres-an-emoji-in-the-project-name look like your case? Are there any emojis in the project paths or file names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem can occur when there are special characters in the project paths, like emojis. The solution is to move the project into a different directory without emojis.

- [Related IntelliJ IDEA issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281300/Scratch-Java-file-wont-run-if-theres-an-emoji-in-the-project-name).